# Convert ajax call string to actual deferred object, is it possible?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, promise

is it possible to convert a string like "$.ajax(...)" to an actual object?

I generate a List with C# with ajax calls to apply to jQuery $.when().

```
arrCalls = ["$.ajax({ url: 'url....' })",
 "$.ajax({ url: 'url....' })"];

$.when.apply($, arrCalls)
.then(...
```

But this is not working. I think because the values are not actual deferreds but strings.

Do I need to keep this ugly code or can I somehow refactor it?

```
$.when(
   @foreach (var item in splitted)
   {
    <text>
    $.ajax(
    '@Html.Raw(Model.GetHost(ViewBag.Foo, ViewBag.Bar))' + '@item', {
        context: { item: '@item' }
    })

    @if (i != count)
    {
       <text>,</text>
    }
    </text>

    i++;
})
.then(function() {
...
```

Comment: Well, you could use eval() but I would highly recommend against that...

Comment: "_I generate a List with C# with **ajax calls**_" - Why? If at all then only generate the options as JSON. These can then be parsed and used for the actual `$.ajax()` calls

Comment: Because I want to get rid of the spaghetti code shown in my post. I think it would be much more readable and cleaner, if I could only do `$.when(arrContainingAjaxCallStrings)...` instead of looping in the view. I want to move the ajax calls itself into javascript files so the seperation is more cleaner.

Comment: As a general guideline, I recommend you only inject data into DOM attributes, or global vars, as you are losing all the benefits of having your JS source in a separate file by generating your JS inside views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the calls to the ajax method (that will be deferred) in an array and call those

This should work.

```
function GetAjaxCall(url) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url  // Set other properties as needed.
    });
}
$(function () {

    var arrUrls = ['@Url.Action("Add")', '@Url.Action("StudentLookup")'];
    var calls = [];
    $.each(arrUrls,function(a, b) {
            calls.push(GetAjaxCall(b));
    });


    $.when.apply($, calls)
        .then(function() {
            console.log('all done');
    });

});
```

Comment: The `GetAjaxCall` appears redundant in your example. Why wrap 1 function call in another function?

Comment: Just to make it clean, if he wants to add additional properties (and to mention that the method simply return the deferred object);

Comment: Again: Why wrap a single function call in a function call? The SO understands that Ajax returns a promise (*incorrectly called a deferred object by both of you*).

Comment: @Shyju Thank you very much. Nice and clean solution. I like it. Now I can do in my view `foo.init([ 'url1', 'url2' ]);` and in my javascript file I can easily convert the array to actual deferreds. So simple and nice. Thanks again.

Comment: @GoneCoding Ah, thank you for the clarification! I meant promisse, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative, and as you do not need the returned values in this example, you can also use the following trick for parallel promises:

```
$(function () {

    var arrUrls = ['@Url.Action("Add")', '@Url.Action("StudentLookup")'];

    var promise; // undefined is a resolved promise to $.when()

    $.each(arrUrls,function(a, url) {
        promise = $.when(promise, $.ajax({
             url: url // Set other properties as needed.
        }));
    });

    promise.then(function() {
            console.log('all done');
    });

});
```

The overhead is very small and it is simpler than the traditional array processing examples you see everywhere using `apply`.

As I mentioned in comment, you are also better off just injecting the minimum JS into views (data attributes or global vars) and leave the bulk of your JS in separate files (easier to debug and makes use of bundling etc).

Comment: Thank you very much for this alternative solution. I will implement this too and then decide which I like better. Thanks.